# How install packages in solution has two projects one .net4.5.2 and another .net4.6.1?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, nuget-package

First of all I was having one project .net 4.5.2 and I was install packages normally, when I create another project .net 4.6.1 I installed packages in that projects but when I back to .net 4.5.2 project and try to install package I get this error:

> Could not install package 'Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs 3.1.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Any advice?

Comment: https://www.fuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs/ That package only supports .NET Standard 2.0, so it requires .NET Framework 4.6.1 and above. Your only option is to upgrade your project to 4.6.1.

Comment: you are right Lex Li